# Provider not found Flutter

Tags: flutter, provider

I want to share some data across different widgets so I decided to use a `ChangeNotifierProvider<Example>` with its relative `Consumer<Example>`. I have already used `Provider`s before but never in this way (in fact I got some errors).

`ChangeNotifierProvider<Example>` has been defined in `menu` page while `Consumer<Example>` in an other widget defined in `menu` too.

Menu page :

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
//...SOme code
ChangeNotifierProvider<Example>(
              create: (context) => Example(),
              child: ShowMultipleAnswers()
//...some code
```

And now I would like to use `Consumer<Example>` inside `ShowMultipleAnswers(`) widget consuming data created in menu like :

```
class ShowMultipleAnswers extends StatefulWidget {
//...some code
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Example>(builder: (context, handler, child) {
//some code
```

But I got these errors :

````
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Example> above this Consumer<Example> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

consider using `builder` like so:
Make sure that Consumer<Example> is under your MultiProvider/Provider<Example>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```


  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```
````

I think the most valid options are 2 :

```
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
```

But I don't know because they should be in the same, I mean `ShowMultipleAnswers()` is the `Provider` child.
Or the second

```
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
```

In this case, following suggestions above, I should use a `builder:(context){}` instead of directly calling `child : ..` but I read that after provider 5 `builder` has been substituted by `create` so I'm confused.

If I'm using wrong widgets tell me please!

Answer (score 0):

The error message exactly specifies and describe your error

`ShowMultipleAnswers` got built using `Menu` context which doesn't have the `Example` provider, thus it throws this error.

you can either use `builder` attribute instead of `child` or wrap your `MaterialApp` with the provider

your code should be something like this:

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
//...SOme code
ChangeNotifierProvider<Example>(
              create: (context) => Example(),
              builder: (context) {
                 return ShowMultipleAnswers();
              } 
//...some code
```

Comment: Can you make a fix example with some code ?

Comment: I edited the answer with an example code

Comment: I can't do this @Omar

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to say that there was an other page between `Menu` and `ShowMultipleAnswers`, like a bridge between them so the real flow was :

`Menu Page` -> `Bridge Page` -> `ShowMultipleAnswers Page`.

I removed this `Bridge Page` and it worked! But I still don't understand why it didn't work, maybe because `Bridge Page` didn't have any references of its `Provider`?